# Docker build unable to install pg gem in Sinatra project

Tags: postgresql, docker, sinatra, bundler, pg

I've reviewed all the posts on SO with similar errors installing the Postgres `pg` gem.

My issue is unique: I can successfully add Postgres to my Sinatra Ruby project via the Gemfile and `bundle install` -- however when building the Docker image it fails installing `pg` with the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170113-7-ottv1k.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
  --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I've tried everything suggested in similar answers:

- Brew install / uninstall,
- gem install / uninstall specifying path to both files: `pg_config` and `libpq-fe.h`
- etc.

As I'm not too familiar with Docker, is there something I'm missing about installing a db with Docker?

Any help much much appreciated in advance. Thank you.

Comment: post your Dockerfile

Answer (score 6):

You got this error because of missing `libpq-dev` package.

Here is the minimal ubuntu-based Dockerfile for installing `pg` gem:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6-slim-buster

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
        build-essential libpq-dev  \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN gem install pg
```

Answer (score 4):

If this is still an issue, make sure your docker image has the `postgresql-client`, `postgresql-dev` and `build-essentials` installed. Include something like

```
...
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add postgresql-client build-dependencies postgresql-dev
...
```

in your Dockerfile before running bundle install. The `postgresql-dev` package contains the headers and other dev-related files.

Comment: To expand on this a bit more, `brew` is installing on your local machine, but Docker doesn't see these changes.  It acts like a virtual machine.  If the client OS doesn't have postgresql, `pg` gem will fail to compile.  Glen's response gets those installed in the client.

Answer (score 0):

I used [dockerfile-rails](https://github.com/rubys/dockerfile-rails) to generate my dockerfile in Rails 7.0.4 and I was having the same issue installing the `pg` gem because of the missing `libpq-dev` package.

Just add the following command to your Dockerfile before your command to bundle install all application gems:

```
# Install packages needed to build gems and node modules
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential curl libpq-dev
```